# How to create AVD without user interaction?

Tags: android, linux, android-virtual-device

I want to create AVD on remote machine through command line. I am using ubuntu machines for both ends.

I am using `android create avd -n <name> -t <target>` command to create AVD.

However, It goes for user interaction asking:

```
Android 4.0.3 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]
```

It waits for user interaction. How to create AVD with headless mode. I may need to customize AVD in some cases (I need to provide YES as answer in other cases Enter key will do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using `expect` library for command line automation. 
You can see the implementation at https://github.com/saurabhjinturkar/avd_creator